# Spring: @Validated and @Async don't work together

Tags: java, spring, validation, asynchronous

I'm trying to use @Validated and @Async in combination.

**Edited:** I want to validate an input object when a method of my service is called. But... nothing happens. My service method is never called. If I remove the @Async annoation from the service method, the validation work fine and <s>the method body is execuded</s> a ValidationContraintException is thrown as expected.

The (partial) configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }   
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
@Validated
public class MyService {

    @Async
    public void doSomethingAsync(@NotNull @Valid final MyBean myBean) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

A compoment that uses the service:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    protected MyService myService;

    public void doSomething(final MyBean myBean) {
        this.myService.doSomethingAsync(myBean); // returned without error
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake? What can I do to make it work?

**Edit #1**

At first I've forgotten to describe that I call my method with an invalid bean to force a validation error.

After some debugging I've found out that the AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor is executed before the MethodValidationInterceptor. This explains the behaviour. If I call my method with an invalid bean, the bean validation is executed within the executor thread. The ValidationConstraintException never reaches my error handler in the main thread and the  call of the method myService.doSomethingAsync(myBean) is leaved without any error.

But I'm confused about this. The apidocs of @EnableAsync decribes that the AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is executed after all other post processors:

*Indicate the order in which the
{@link org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor}
should be applied. The default is {@link Ordered#LOWEST_PRECEDENCE} in order to run
after all other post-processors, so that it can add an advisor to
existing proxies rather than double-proxy.*

So I would expect that the AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor is executed after all other interceptors for my method.

**Edit #2**

The dependency cglib:cglib:3.1 is already added as project dependency and `@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)` seem to have no effect.

**Edit #3**

I've played around with the order attribute of `@EnableAsync` and the `MethodValidationPostProcessor`.

If I set an order of `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` to the MethodValidationPostProcessor, my service bean cannot be found for autowiring (for some reason), `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1` works.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        final MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();

        processor.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1);
        return processor;
    }   
}
```

With a debugger I can see, that the order of the post processors is as expected. The `MethodValidationPostProcessor` is now ordered before the `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. But this has absolutely no effect to the order of the method incerceptors of my method `doSomethingAsync`.

**Edit #4**

For the moment I just removed any @Async annoations from my code. Until now I don't have a solution. The problem still exists... :(

Comment: Try using `@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)` and also add CGLIB to you classpath if it's not already there

Answer (score 0):

Both interceptors have the same `order` default value so the order in which they are invoked is not deterministic. In your case, the async annotation is processed first.

You can fix that easily by providing an explicit order for your validation method, based on other interceptors you might have on your services, something like

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    processor.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1);
    return processor;
}
```

You can also provide an order to `@EnableAsync` to make it explicit that you are relying to a certain order.

Comment: I've tried to handle this by the order, but for some reason it has no effect. No matter if I order async with 0 and validation (MethodValidationPostProcessor) with 1 or async with 1 and validation with 0... the async method intercepter is always called first.

Comment: Can you create a simple example and push it to the [spring framework issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues) repo please?